# How do I change the size of the parent div without affecting the children nodes displayed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am developing a dashboard application where the user can view information regarding cryptocurrencies, I have fetched the information using coingecko's API, now I want to render the information in a particular place on the page, here is a screenshot of the project I am working on

[image]

Here is the React code and the CSS for this part of the page that is being rendered

```
import React from 'react'
import { Typography } from 'antd'
import "./PriceCard.css"

const { Text, Title } = Typography
const PriceCards = ({ cryptoProps }) => {

    if (!cryptoProps[0]){
        return <></>
    }
    return (
        <div className='priceCard'>
            <div className="cryptoInfo">
                <img src={cryptoProps[0].image}/>
            </div>

            <div className="cryptoInfo">
                <Title level={3}>All Time High</Title >
                <Text strong={true}>$ {cryptoProps[0].ath}</Text>
            </div>

            <div className="cryptoInfo">
                <Title level={3}>Market Cap</Title >
                <Text strong={true}>$ {cryptoProps[0].market_cap}</Text>
            </div>

            <div className="cryptoInfo">
                <Title level={3}>Price Change (24 hours)</Title >
                <Text strong={true}>{cryptoProps[0].price_change_percentage_24h} %</Text>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default PriceCards
```

```
.priceCard {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 10vh;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10;
    padding-right: 80em;
    border-style: dashed;
}

.cryptoInfo {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    width: 35%;
    height: 35%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

As you can see the parent div, with the className 'priceCard' has a size that spans the whole page, but I want it to be sized where its just on the top left, where all the information is being presented, but the issue is, once I try to meddle around with the CSS, it messes up the whole page and the information being presented.I still want the information being presented in a grid-like fashion how it is done right now, without anything being moved if I change any CSS to the 'priceCard' div.

Comment: Use css flexbox

Comment: where? which node?

Comment: The parent node priceCard

Comment: I would avoid floats _and_ absolute positioning. Floats are obsolete and absolute positioning is troublesome unless you actually need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `float` that's why the boxes move. Here I have added `grid`:

```css
.priceCard {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 10vh;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10;
    /*padding-right: 80em;*/
    border-style: dashed;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr
}

.cryptoInfo {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='priceCard'>
            <div class="cryptoInfo">
                <img src={cryptoProps[0].image} alt="image"/>
            </div>

            <div class="cryptoInfo">
                All Time High               
            </div>

            <div class="cryptoInfo">
                Market Cap
            </div>

            <div class="cryptoInfo">
                Price Change (24 hours)
            </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:grid;` to have fixed grid to display the content.

```css
.priceCard {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 10vh;
    position: absolute;
    border-style: dashed;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.cryptoInfo {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='priceCard'>
            <div class="cryptoInfo">
                <img src={cryptoProps[0].image} alt="image"/>
            </div>

            <div class="cryptoInfo">
                All Time High               
            </div>

            <div class="cryptoInfo">
                Market Cap
            </div>

            <div class="cryptoInfo">
                Price Change (24 hours)
            </div>
</div>
```